# Android : Issue with memory for large Bitmap objects

Tags: android

Lots been said, written, vented out ;) on this already, I know. But my question is a bit different. I realize that there is issue with using large bitmap objects in Android. In my Android App, I need to use large bitmaps in various places. cannot help it. I tried various things listed in stackoverflow. One that I want to try but not able to is to avoid using ARBG_8888. The App crashes exactly at that line many times. I have an ImageView where I load an initial large bitmap. Then the user can make some markings in the bitmap and then I need to save the whole image (i.e. the original bitmap + the user's markings). Am trying this with this code I got from stackoverflow:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(Context context, View view) {

    Log.d(logtag, "loadBitmapFromView");
    Bitmap bitmap;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    // These help in saving/recycling the bitmap memory 
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;

    Bitmap dummy = null;
    try {
        dummy = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open("icon_add.png"), new Rect(-1,-1,-1,-1), options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getLayoutParams().width,
        view.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            //  bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( dummy, view.getLayoutParams().width,
            //              view.getLayoutParams().height, false);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height);
    view.draw(c);
    Log.d(logtag, "loadBitmapFromView: width:" + view.getLayoutParams().width);
    c = null;

    return bitmap;
}
```

How do I avoid using ARGB_8888 in the above code? Can someone please help?
I removed it from many other places in the code, but, in the above snippet, am left in vain.

I tried using an initial dummy object (you can see the object 'dummy' in the above code) to create a scaled bitmap object ( with createScaledBitmap() which necessarily asks for a source bitmap ) and then tried to load the canvas, but the generated image is having only the dummy object (icon_add.png) and not the one from the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

you can show image in device specific height width....then you don't get out of memory for imagesize.
this is code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static int getDeviceWidth(Activity activity) {
        int deviceWidth = 0;

        Point size = new Point();
        WindowManager windowManager = activity.getWindowManager();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
            deviceWidth = size.x;
        } else {
            Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
            deviceWidth = display.getWidth();
        }
        return deviceWidth;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static int getDeviceHeight(Activity activity) {
        int deviceHeight = 0;

        Point size = new Point();
        WindowManager windowManager = activity.getWindowManager();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
            deviceHeight = size.y;
        } else {
            Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
            deviceHeight = display.getHeight();
        }
        return deviceHeight;
    }
```

you can use device height and width..and set this image in imageview..

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(viewHomeScreen);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        params.height = getDeviceHeight(activity);
        params.width = getDevicewidth(activity);
FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(viewHomeScreen);

        framelayout.addView(image, 0, params);
```

i hope if you use device specific height and width then your image memory issue will be solved.

Comment: thanks @dipali, but my requirement is to show in the actual width / height. I cannot scale it down.

Comment: ok then your image is small and ur android device is big .right.so you have to set image as per android device.right?

Comment: no @dipali, I need to load the original image, irrespective of the device size